# Adapter loading slowly android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-arrayadapter, progressdialog

Hi I am working with Adapter in my app.

The updateUI() method has stuff has follows:

```
public void updateUI() {


musicAlbumAdapter = new MusicAlbumAdapter(getActivity(),
        R.layout.music_album_row_layout, storeAlbumDetails);

music_album_listview.setAdapter(musicAlbumAdapter);
music_album_listview.setSelection(savedListPosition);

/*
 * LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(
 * R.layout.footer_layout, null);
 * 
 * list.addFooterView(listFooterView);
 */

//confirm with adapter that returning the view at very first time then cancel the dialog

if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
pDialog.cancel();
if(pDialogLazyLoading != null && pDialogLazyLoading.isShowing())
pDialogLazyLoading.cancel();
```

}

but the ProgressDialog pDialog closed before the data loading. The page looks blank for few seconds. Like the image below.

[image]

**Here I have used ArrayAdapter:**

```
public class MusicAlbumAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AlbumDetails> {

private Context context;

private ArrayList<AlbumDetails> albumDetails;

/*
 * private ArrayList<String> albumTitle; private ArrayList<String>
 * albumMusic; private ArrayList<String> albumImage;
 */

public MusicAlbumAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<AlbumDetails> albumDetails) {
    super(context, resource, albumDetails);
    this.context = context;
    this.albumDetails = albumDetails;

    /*
     * this.albumTitle = albumTitle; this.albumMusic = albumMusic;
     * this.albumImage = albumImage;
     */
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_album_row_layout,
            parent, false);

    try {

        TextView music_album_title = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.music_album_row_title);

        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        music_album_title.setTypeface(FontTypefaces.getHero(activity));
        music_album_title.setText(albumDetails.get(position)
                .getAlbumTitle());
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    }
    try {

        TextView music_album_music = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.music_album_row_music);
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        music_album_music.setTypeface(FontTypefaces.getHero(activity));
        music_album_music.setText(albumDetails.get(position)
                .getAlbumMusic());

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    }

    try {

        ImageView music_album_image = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.music_album_row_image);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(albumDetails.get(position).getAlbumImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.rlogo) // optional
                .error(R.drawable.rlogo) // optional
                .into(music_album_image);

    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    }

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: You missed runOnUiThread();

Comment: @Iqbal I tried runOnUIThread() . Same result.